# Associated Automation not showing Tests in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, microsoft-test-manager

I have the following problem where Associated Automation not showing tests.

The project has been checked in and the Unit Tests show up fine on Test Explorer

When I query and search for a Test Case in TFS then attempt to link a Unit Test to the Test case via the associate button, nothing appears in the Choose Test window.

Any help please?

Comment: Do you run this query in Visual Studio?
Is the solution that contains the tests opened/loaded in Visual Studio when you are trying to add this tests?

Comment: It is working now, the Unit Tests are appearing